# Enabling xdebug with phpstorm on mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, phpstorm, xdebug

Before upgrading my macbook to El Capitan I had a sweet setup of Phpstorm 9, php 5.6 (via homebrew), xdebug (via homebrew).

For the last month or so, however, I have been breakin my head, trying to figure out how to make that setup work again.

I would appreciate any ideas you guys might have.

Thanks, Eyal

P.S.
Here are my settings:

*xdebug version and ide key*
[image: xdebug version and ide key]

*xdebug remote settings*
[image: xdebug remote settings]

*xdebug session cookie*
[image: xdebug session cookie]

*xdebug port in phpstorm*
[image: xdebug port in phpstorm]

*PHP configuration in phpstorm*
[image: PHP configuration in phpstorm]

*Debug validation in phpstorm*
[image: Debug validation in phpstorm]

*xdebug log*

```
Log opened at 2015-11-19 22:33:49
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 127.0.0.1:9000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///Users/eyalsh/Sites/test/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="73266" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="2.3.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2015 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2015-11-19 22:33:49
```

Comment: 1) Please provide xdebug log 2) Make sure that your firewall allows PhpStorm to receive incoming connections on xdebug port

Comment: Well .. it's connected (to some service on 9000 port). It says that it is hit for `/Users/eyalsh/Sites/test/index.php` file -- can you please verify that path (pay attention to the letter case as well) with what you are seeing in PhpStorm?

Comment: 2) Exit PhpStorm completely and run `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` -- what services are running on TCP 9000 port? 3) if none -- launch PhpStorm again, open that project and run that command again (without doing any debugging actions/buttons). Any difference?

Comment: @LazyOne before starting phpstorm: 4 php-fpm services listen on port 9000. After starting phpstorm and clicking on the debug listen button, phpstorm listens to port 9000 (the 4 fpm-php services that listen on 9000 are still there). PS> the path is verified

Comment: Thnx. Please change xdebug port (in both `php.ini` and PhpStorm) to some another port (e.g. 9001 -- verify that it is not occupied before doing that using the same command). You may need to restart your web browser to see those changes picked up. Right now there seems to be a conflict with `php-fpm` (same ports)

Comment: THANK YOU !!!!! [Have a million cookies](http://freeinternetcookies.com/) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the provided info: please change xdebug port (in both `php.ini` and PhpStorm) to some another port (e.g. 9001) and verify that it is not occupied before doing that using the same `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN` command.

Right now there seems to be a conflict with `php-fpm` (both programs using the same ports).

**P.S.**
You may need to restart your web server to see those changes picked up from `php.ini`.

Comment: Thank you! I just ran into this problem and your suggestion of configuring a different port did it for me.

Comment: Thanks! Working on MacOS Big Sur.