# How do I configure Xdebug and PhpStorm with Caddy and PHP-FPM

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, caddy

I have Xdebug running as part of PHP5.6 installed on OSX with Homebrew. I can run PHP-FPM and serve my site fine, however debugging using X-debug does not seem to work.

Here is my ext-xdebug.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php56-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Comment: At minimum change xdebug port to be other than `9000` as php-fpm uses it by default. Use `9001` for example (needs to be changed in both php.ini as well as PhpStorm settings): http://stackoverflow.com/a/33816324/783119; http://stackoverflow.com/a/38644688/783119

Answer (score 1):

php-fpm usually runs on port 9000.
This is also the default port for xdebug.

Adjust your xdebug setting in php-fpm to use port 9001
If you used brew to install, they are found here:

```
/usr/local/etc/php/5.6/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini
```

Add the following to your ext-xdebug.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php56-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
xdebug.remote_port=9001
```

[Docs for those xdebug settings.](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_connect_back)

Adjust phpStorm to use port 9001 for debugging.
It's found under preferences -> language & frameworks -> php debug.

Just for completeness, here's my Caddyfile

```
:80
log  ./caddy.log

root ./html

fastcgi / 127.0.0.1:9000 php {
env WHEREAMI dev
} 

rewrite {
    if {path} not_match ^\/wp-admin
    to {path} {path}/ /index.php?_url={uri}
}
```

Restart Caddy, php-fpm and phpstorm and you should be good do go.